# NodeJS socket data splitting

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

When I need to split data I have to convert it to string.
Here is my data handler function:

```
  socket.on('data', function (data) {
    var str = data.toString().split("|");
    switch(str[0]){
        case "setUser":
        setUser(str[1], socket);
        break;
        case "joinChannel":
        joinChannel(str[1], socket);
        break;
    }

  });
```

When I send data like "setUser|Name" and then "joinChannel|main" from AS3 client. NodeJS reads it as one data packet.
My question is how to make that as two different data packets?

Comment: What character separates the two pieces? A New line? You have no control over the packets themselves.

Comment: AS3 code:  server.send("setUser|"+name_txt.text)+"\n";
 server.send("joinChannel|aha")+"\n";

Comment: Did you try my answer? Also, the code in your comment won't put newlines in the data sent, it appends a newline to the result of the send command...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you would buffer all of the data together, and then parse it as one string. Or if you need to part it as it comes in, then you would do the splitting in the `data` callback and keep track of any leftover partial commands to prepend on the net chunk received.

```
var data = '';
socket.setEncoding('utf8');
socket.on('data', function(chunk) {
  data += chunk;
});
socket.on('end', function() {

  var lines = data.split('\n');
  lines.forEach(function(line) {
    var parts = line.split('|');
    switch (parts[0]) {
      case 'setUser':
        setUser(str[1], socket);
        break;
      case 'joinChannel':
        joinChannel(str[1], socket);
        break;
    }
  });
});
```